# Duplicate ID error when creating fragments in different Controllers

Tags: sapui5

So... I'm building an application that is basically a CRUD. On this application, I have the following views / controllers: *VisitEdit* and *RequestNew*.

At the *RequestNew* controller, I have a function that handles the press of a button:

```
onRequestNewAddCustomerPress: function(oEvent) {
  if( !this.oAddCustomerDialog ){
    this.oAddCustomerDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("com.sap.lccapp.fragment.AddCustomer", this);
  }
  this.oAddCustomerDialog.openBy(oEvent.getSource());
},
```

And I have at this same Controller the `onExit` function. It is now empty, because I have made a LOT of test with the `.destroy()` function of this object (`oAddCustomerDialog`) and it continues popping up the error.

---

The problem is; on the *VisitEdit* controller, when I try to use the same dialog for the second time, with the same code as above, it shows the following error:

> Adding element with duplicate id 'addCustomerNameField'

The ID `"addCustomerNameField"` is from my first element inside my fragment.

Although I have the 'if verification' on both methods and because it is in different controllers, the last 'if' that is being verified has the object (`this.oAddCustomerDialog`) undefined (BUT IT SHOULD NOT HAS UNDEFINED VALUE) and it is creating again the `sap.ui.xmlfragment`.

---

Fragment definition: http://dontpad.com/stackoverflowquestionsapui5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can associate a unique ID when instantiating fragments. This way this unique ID will be prefix with the IDs of the control the fragment contains.

So, two different codes will be:

```js
onRequestNewAddCustomerPress: function(oEvent) {
  if (!this.oAddCustomerDialog) {
    this.oAddCustomerDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("idOnNewRequest","com.sap.lccapp.fragment.AddCustomer", this);
  }
  this.oAddCustomerDialog.openBy(oEvent.getSource());
},
```

and then:

```js
onVisitEditAddCustomerPress: function(oEvent) {
  if (!this.oAddCustomerDialog) {
    this.oAddCustomerDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("idOnEdit","com.sap.lccapp.fragment.AddCustomer", this);
  }
  this.oAddCustomerDialog.openBy(oEvent.getSource());
},
```

Also, do check the following documentation topic: *[IDs in Declarative XML or HTML Fragments](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/0715706772ed43f389d2ab9b381ef8ec)*

EDIT: If these fragments are being called from two different views, **best to use the ID of the view.** I would modify the code to instantiate fragment as below:

```js
this.oAddCustomerDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(this.getView().getId(), "com.sap.lccapp.fragment.AddCustomer", this);
```

---

As of UI5 1.58, the factory function `sap.ui.*fragment` is deprecated. Please use [`Fragment.load`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Fragment/methods/sap.ui.core.Fragment.load) instead!

```js
Fragment.load({
  id: this.getView().getId(),
  name: "com.sap.lccapp.fragment.AddCustomer",
  controller: this,
}); // returns a promise
```